# Android Progress dialog for multiple progresses

Tags: android

I am using a ProgressDialog for "Loading data....". Can I set it up for 5 different types of data ?

```
Loading data 1 ....progress.... complete

Loading data 2 ....progress.... complete

Loading data 3 ....progress.... complete

Loading data 4 ....progress.... complete

Loading data 5 ....progress.... complete
```

Is this possible on a single dialog box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need to create a custom dialog (or dialog fragment). Progress dialog only supports a single progress bar. Basically, create your own layout and add your 5 progress bar widgets.

Here's a link to information on how to create a custom dialog,

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Here's a link to the progress bar widget,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html